# Why the scrapping data from a somewebsite is difficult?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, automation

I have beed trying to learn a little bit about python automation, in which i'm trying to learn web-scrapping.
i have chosen to made a discord bot which accepts a user id of player of a game called "brawlhalla" and show the details of the player from some live tracking websites
and my approach was to accept a playercode from the user and head to [https://brawlhallastats.herokuapp.com/player/?player="UserID"](https://brawlhallastats.herokuapp.com/player/?player=%22UserID%22) and using a library like pandas or beautifull soup

But the real issue is that when is extract data from the website using pandas then absolutely no tables are detected and when i try to do this using beautifulSoup it is now showing the data

Feels like they are trying to protect the data somehow.............

i suggest to run this script and enter the code : 65340087

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
#importing modules 

code = input("enter the code :")
url = "https://brawlhallastats.herokuapp.com/player/?player="+code 
print(url)
r = requests.get(url)
htmlContent = r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlContent,'html.parser')

#getting the username but not working
playername = soup.find('span',{'id':'playerName'})
print(playername)

#getting the playerlever but not working
playerLevel = soup.find('span',{'id':'playerLevel'})
print(playerLevel)
```

the output will be:

```
https://brawlhallastats.herokuapp.com/player/?player=65340087
<span id="playerName" style="text-shadow: 1px 1px #eee; color:#AAAAAA"> RupRep444</span>
<span id="playerLevel"><b>Level:</b> 32.85<br/></span>
```

but if you head to the url : https://brawlhallastats.herokuapp.com/player/?player=65340087
you will notice that the playerName is something else "HetoskiWannaWeed" and the player Level is : 58

I need a very great help regarding this issue because this is the first real-time project i'm trying to build and struggling with tons and tons of issues

Answer (score 0):

The data you see on the page is loaded with JavaScript, so `beautifulsoup` doesn't see it. Solution could be using their Ajax URL and request the Json data using `requests`:

```py
import json
import requests

player_id = 65340087
api_url = (
    "https://brawlhallastats.herokuapp.com/api/submit-form3-by-id?player={}"
)

data = requests.get(api_url.format(player_id)).json()

# uncomment to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

print(data["name"], data["level"])
```

Prints:

```
HetoskiWannaWeed 58
```

Comment: i just dont know how to thank you
can i like know your gmail account ? because i want to talk to you regarding the code

Comment: it is an honor to get my problem solved by such a great personality

Comment: `api_url = (
    "https://brawlhallastats.herokuapp.com/api/submit-form3-by-id?player={}"
)` what exactly this line of code does

`data = requests.get(api_url.format(player_id)).json()` and what does this line does

Comment: @Het `"https://brawlhallastats.herokuapp.com/api/submit-form3-by-id?player={}"` is a string. `{}` at the end of the URL is used by `str.format` to be replaced by `player_id`.